# Is there a way to get a File path to a Drawable compiled into the project?

Tags: android, bluetooth, drawable

I am sending image files to a bluetooth printer using the following code...

```
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)).toString());
                values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, device.getAddress());
                values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
                Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
                values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
                Uri contentUri = c.getContentResolver().insert( BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
                L.d("Insert contentUri: " + contentUri + "  to device: "+ device.getName());
```

This works perfectly for files on the sdcard (note the file path being passed in, on the second line of this sample).

But I'd like to now allow the user to print images that are compiled into the app.

I realize that the drawable folder doesn't have a direct path to it because of how android sorts its images based on device resolution, so, I'm curious what the code would be to get something I could pass to this printing method so that it would print images embedded in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer to the question is "no".

Answer (score 0):

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/image_name");
values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, uri);
```

Comment: I don't believe you can access your drawables in this way (as I said in my question). Did you test this?

Comment: Hi Doc. I should have addressed that in my post. I think the path is correct as Android looks in various directories based on screen size and density. Android doesn't move the files around; it has a hierarchy of 'drawable' places to look for files. Nevertheless, I did not test the suggested path. As an alternate suggestion, I often put .html files in the "assets" folder (parallel to "res") and access them like this: "file:///android_asset/help.html". I hope one of these solutions works for you.

Comment: I'm testing it now. I have used this methodology before, but I was under the impression that specifically as it relates to drawables this wouldn't work... will have an update shortly.

Comment: Hi Dr. I'm still low-key looking into this as it is an interesting problem, and I may run tests, but in the meantime I want to verify with you that for "image_name" in my suggestion that you have tried both with and without the filename extension (i.e. "image_name" and "image_name.png").